# How do I check the contents of a resource-group from Azure cloud shell C#?

Tags: c#, azure

[image]

I am trying to launch a basic app from Azure cloud shell.  As you can see from the picture above, the app is not found in the resource group.  As you can see from the picture below, the resource group exists.  I want to take a look inside the resource group to see if the app is there or if it has a different name.  How do I list the contents of the resource group?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

You can use the `--resource-group` parameter to query only resources in a specific resource group.

```
az resource list --resource-group <resource-group-name>
```

The previous answer is less efficient because it queries every ressources and then filters locally.

**Old Answer :**

```
az resource list --query "[?resourceGroup == '<resource-group-name>']"
```

Azure CLI provide the `--query` parameter to execute [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) query on commands' results.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) for more informations.